# I want to call JSON data from json file to html table

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap-4

### I want to call JSON data from json file to html table. but, the error is coming again and again. Why? can someone help me?

I want to print JSON data in HTML table. "Hello" is Question and it have 4 option and 1 answer.

But, JSON data is not coming in HTML page.

To check this I put

tag with class demo and call "Hello" only at this position but, no any data is coming.

I am also using console.log(data); to check JSON data is calling or not. but, it shows an error.

> Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

```js
var data = {
  "mydata":[
      {
        "Hello":"abcd",
        "opt":["ab","cd","ef","gh"],
        "ans":"cd"
      },
      {
        "Hello":"efgh",
        "opt":["ab","cd","ef","gh"],
        "answer":"ab"
      },
      {
        "Hello":"ijkl",
        "opt":["ab","cd","ef","gh"],
        "answer":"ef"
      },
      {
        "Hello":"mnop",
        "opt":["ab","cd","ef","gh"],
        "answer":"gh"
      }
    ]
  };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <p class="demo"></p>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Hello</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

<script>

  var myobj = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(myobj);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What's happening here?

Actually the `data` variable is not a JSON at all (it's may seem like a JSON but it's not) and **you can easily find it out by using `typeof` method**. So take a look at the below snippet.

```js
var data = {
  "mydata": [{
      "Hello": "abcd",
      "opt": ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"],
      "ans": "cd"
    },
    {
      "Hello": "efgh",
      "opt": ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"],
      "answer": "ab"
    },
    {
      "Hello": "ijkl",
      "opt": ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"],
      "answer": "ef"
    },
    {
      "Hello": "mnop",
      "opt": ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"],
      "answer": "gh"
    }
  ]
};

console.log('data type is:', typeof data);
console.log('JSON data type is:', typeof JSON.stringify(data));
```

**JSON's exists with type `string`**, but in your case, **`data` variable is an `object`** so whenever you try to get the type of it, it will return `object`. But when you stringify it with built-in methods it will show as `string`.

### How to solve this?

So in the end, **for reading `data` values you just need to get `mydata` property within the `data` like this: `data.mydata` and then iterate through it by `for` loops.**

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
var data = {
  "mydata": [{
      "Hello": "abcd",
      "opt": ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"],
      "ans": "cd"
    },
    {
      "Hello": "efgh",
      "opt": ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"],
      "answer": "ab"
    },
    {
      "Hello": "ijkl",
      "opt": ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"],
      "answer": "ef"
    },
    {
      "Hello": "mnop",
      "opt": ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"],
      "answer": "gh"
    }
  ]
};


data.mydata.forEach((item, index) => console.log(`item ${index} in mydata is:`, item))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding how JSON works. Your *data* is ALREADY in JSON compatible state.

You only need JSON.parse() to reverse the effects of someone used JSON.stringify() your data structure.

For example:

```
   console.log(data)
   var myobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
   console.log(myobj);
```

The two console logs would give "roughly" the same output.